# Is it correct to write $argmin(x, y) \sum_i^n |p_{x_i} - x| + |p_{y_i} - y| = argmin(x) \sum_i^n |p_{x_i} - x| + argmin(y) \sum_i^n |p_{y_i} - y| $?

Tags: calculus, optimization, notation

$argmin(x, y)  \sum_i^n |p_{x_i} - x| + |p_{y_i} - y| = argmin(x)  \sum_i^n |p_{x_i} - x| + argmin(y) \sum_i^n |p_{y_i} - y|  $

Is it a legit way of separating argmins to show independence of $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct, as both terms on the right hand side are independent from one another.